# update Axios Url with Onclick event in react

Tags: reactjs

I am working on an `API` using `axios`:

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      url:[],
      title:'anime',
      limit:6,
    }
    this.more_button.bind(this)
  }

  componentDidMount() {

  //limit is on the end of the url
  const limit= this.state.limit

     axios.get(`http://api.giphy.com/v1/gifs/search?q=sth&api_key=MY_KEY&limit=` + limit)
      .then(res => {
        const url= res.data.data;
        this.setState({ url });
      })

  }
```

I want to change `limit` when i click on a button;
and i do it like this:

```
  more_button=()=>{

      this.setState((previousState) => {
        return { limit: previousState.limit + 6 };
    });

    this.componentDidMount();

  }
```

The problem is that i should click that button twice in order to work.

render part:

```
  render(){
    return(
      <div className="container">
              <button
              onClick={this.more_button} >
              Give me More!
              </button>
  )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

ComponentDidMount is a lifecycle method. Don't call this function manually,Try below code.

```
componentDidMount() {
  //limit is on the end of the url
  this.apiCall();
  }

 apiCall() {
      const limit= this.state.limit
      axios.get(`http://api.giphy.com/v1/gifs/search?q=sth&api_key=MY_KEY&limit=` + limit)
      .then(res => {
        const url= res.data.data;
        this.setState({ url });
      })
 }


more_button = () => {

  this.setState((previousState) => {
    return { limit: previousState.limit + 6 };
});
this.apiCall();
}
```

Change your render onClick method like:

```
onClick={()=>this.more_button}
```

Finally add extra line in constructor:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      url:[],
      title:'anime',
      limit:6,
    }
     this.apiCall = this.apiCall.bind(this);
     this.more_button = this.more_button.bind(this);
  }
```

Comment: got error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'state' of undefined`  `const limit= this.state.limit`